# What is the correct way to use fmt::sprintf?

Tags: c++, fmt

I'm trying to optimize my software and to do that I need to change the way I store and draw things.

Many people say that fmt is way faster than iostream at doing those things, yet I'm sitting here and trying to understand what I did wrong.

The old code is working:

```cpp
auto type = actor->GetName();
char name[0x64];
if (type.find("AI") != std::string::npos)
sprintf(name, "AI [%dm]", dist);
```

The new one isn't:

```cpp
auto type = actor->GetName();
char name[0x64];
if (type.find("AI") != std::string::npos)
fmt::sprintf("AI [%dm]", dist);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sooo where do you think `fmt::sprintf` stores its output? What is that `char name[0x20]` doing there above `sprintf`? And any specific reason why not use `fmt::format`?

Comment: Instead of taking an output buffer as an argument, `fmt::sprintf` returns a `std::string`. Try using that return value.

Comment: You're still not using the return value of your call to `fmt::sprintf`.

Comment: Unless you do truly massive amounts of formatted I/O (which you shouldn't be doing), performance of either version doesn't matter.

Comment: Read fmt's docs to see how to use functions.

Comment: How do you expect `fmt::sprintf("AI [%dm]", dist);` to work anyway? What is the desired effect of this function call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@NathanPierson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12334309/nathan-pierson) mentioned in comments, `fmt::sprintf()` return a `std::string`, which you are ignoring. `fmt::sprintf()` does not fill a `char[]` buffer (not that you are passing one in to it anyway, like you were with `::sprintf()`).

Change this:

```cpp
char name[0x64];
fmt::sprintf("AI [%dm]", dist);
```

To this:

```cpp
std::string name = fmt::sprintf("AI [%dm]", dist);
```

And then you can use `name` as needed.  If you need to pass it to a function that expects a `(const) char*`, you can use `name.c_str()` or `name.data()` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> Many people say that fmt is **way faster** than iostream at doing those things, yet I'm sitting here and trying to understand what I did wrong.

In addition to Remy Lebeau's correct answer, there's another point. You mentioned speed as a consideration. In that case, you may want avoid constructing an `std::string`, and use `fmt::format_to_n()` (or [`std::format_to_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format_to_n)) to format into your char buffer directly:

```
auto type = actor->GetName();
char name[0x64];
if (type.find("AI") != std::string::npos) {
    fmt::format_to_n(name, 0x64, "AI [{}m]", dist);
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't think `fmt` has a function which targets an existing buffer *and* uses printf format specifiers.